# when i rotate the image to 45 degrees overlay coming out of the bounds in android

Tags: android, rotation

here i have a quick question on cropping related.

i used this library for cropping

here is the some snippet code in MainActivity cropperSample :

```
 rotateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cropImageView.rotateImage(45);
        }
    });
```

https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

here cropping is working perfect i don't have any questions on cropping.but my question is when i rotate the image to 45 degrees overlay coming out of the image bounds. image shown below.

[image]

my requirement is overlay should be inside and movable to the any corner not coming out of image bounds if the image in any angle.

i googled and tried so many ways but no use..

if any one have idea please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: thanks for reply... just i changed the angle value in cropImageView.rotateImage(45) thats it...

Comment: so you have solved it?

Comment: @Elltz i'm still searching for solution..

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement:

> Overlay should be inside and movable to the any
>   corner not coming out of image bounds if the image in any angle.

You can easily achieve this by following steps:

1. If you have used gradle `compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'` to include Cropper mean, remove that line.
2. Download and import cropper as a Module into Android studio and add as a dependency to your application.
3. Since the default color used to paint the border between overlay and image is `translucent(#B0000000)`, change it to `Black(#000000)`. It is defined in **com.edmodo.cropper.util.PaintUtl.java#DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR_ID**. That's it now if you build and run, you get the desired output like below:

[image: Cropper-Sample.png]

*Note:* My Personal suggestion, I faced OutOfMemoryException multiple times, the library is not production ready. Please go for some good alternative libraries.

Comment: thanks for reply. and i am not using gradle, i'm using eclipse. how could i solve this in eclipse.

Comment: @user512 If you have imported `Cropper` as a library(If added as a .jar file then remove it and import as a library project) project then goto `PaintUtil.java` in Cropper project and edit the specified constant, rerun the project.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bitmap rotation inside view, you can rotate the whole view around it's center. Then the cropping rectangle will also be rotated. So, then you code will look like:

```
rotateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        cropImageView.setPivotX(cropImageView.getWidth() / 2);
        cropImageView.setPivotY(cropImageView.getHeight() / 2);
        cropImageView.setRotation(45);
    }
});
```

That's giving me next result as expected:

[image]

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

I finally got the solution. You should rotate cropped bitmap and change it's background color to transparent if the whole view has been rotated. This can be done in two ways:

***First way***, you can fork and change the source code of `getCroppedImage()` method in `CropImageView` class:

```
public Bitmap getCroppedImage() {

    final Rect displayedImageRect = ImageViewUtil.getBitmapRectCenterInside(mBitmap, mImageView);

    // Get the scale factor between the actual Bitmap dimensions and the
    // displayed dimensions for width.
    final float actualImageWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
    final float displayedImageWidth = displayedImageRect.width();
    final float scaleFactorWidth = actualImageWidth / displayedImageWidth;

    // Get the scale factor between the actual Bitmap dimensions and the
    // displayed dimensions for height.
    final float actualImageHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    final float displayedImageHeight = displayedImageRect.height();
    final float scaleFactorHeight = actualImageHeight / displayedImageHeight;

    // Get crop window position relative to the displayed image.
    final float cropWindowX = Edge.LEFT.getCoordinate() - displayedImageRect.left;
    final float cropWindowY = Edge.TOP.getCoordinate() - displayedImageRect.top;
    final float cropWindowWidth = Edge.getWidth();
    final float cropWindowHeight = Edge.getHeight();

    // Scale the crop window position to the actual size of the Bitmap.
    final float actualCropX = cropWindowX * scaleFactorWidth;
    final float actualCropY = cropWindowY * scaleFactorHeight;
    final float actualCropWidth = cropWindowWidth * scaleFactorWidth;
    final float actualCropHeight = cropWindowHeight * scaleFactorHeight;

    // Crop the subset from the original Bitmap.
    Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap,
                                                     (int) actualCropX,
                                                     (int) actualCropY,
                                                     (int) actualCropWidth,
                                                     (int) actualCropHeight);

    //rotate cropped bitmap and change it's background color to transparent
    if (getRotation() > 0 && getRotation() < 360) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(getRotation());
        croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(croppedBitmap, 0, 0, croppedBitmap.getWidth(), croppedBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(croppedBitmap.getWidth(), croppedBitmap.getHeight(), croppedBitmap.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.drawBitmap(croppedBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        return result;
    }

    return croppedBitmap;
}
```

***Second way,*** if you don't want to fork the repo, you can do it like this:

```
    findViewById(R.id.crop_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap croppedBitmap = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
            //rotate bitmap and change it's background color to transparent
            if (cropImageView.getRotation() > 0 && cropImageView.getRotation() < 360) {
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(cropImageView.getRotation());
                croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(croppedBitmap, 0, 0, croppedBitmap.getWidth(), croppedBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

                Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(croppedBitmap.getWidth(), croppedBitmap.getHeight(), croppedBitmap.getConfig());
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
                canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                canvas.drawBitmap(croppedBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            }

            resultImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    });
```

The result will be like this:
[image]

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, its not worked because when we rotate the view and apply crop and without rotate the view and apply crop will give you the same result.. so its not worked..

Comment: So, as I understand, you want image to be cropped with the 45 degrees rotation too ?

Comment: no no... its just for example.. i want to crop image in any angle.

Comment: I see, you want the cropped image should also be rotated, right?

Comment: yes at the same time we should move the overlay to any corner, while image is in any angle.

Comment: sorry @rom4ek.. i tried it already but this is not the right solution. because cropped image should be fix to the resultimageview. resultimageview should be with only cropped image i dont want to display any background..  and thanks for ur reply..

Comment: So, as I understand you want to ImageVIew morph to cropped bitmap form, right?

Comment: sorry i didn't get u? what is morph?

Comment: You want ImageView shape should be the same as a cropped bitmap, right?

Comment: ya .. is it possible?

Comment: No, if you take a look at any library that changes shape of ImageView, in code they just draw bitmap in needed form, without changing ImageView bounds.